# Impulse Response in a VAR model - all endogenous variables

Tags: vector-autoregression, impulse-response

I am trying to understand the implications of an IRF. Specifically in a VAR system.

Here is documentation I looked at:

https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/vector_ar.html#impulse-response-analysis

https://www.r-econometrics.com/timeseries/irf/

https://towardsdatascience.com/multivariate-autoregressive-models-and-impulse-response-analysis-cb5ead9b2b68

What I understand,  their main purpose is to describe the evolution of a model’s variables in reaction to a one-unit shock in one variable an its effect on another variable **while keeping all other variables constant.** -(This last part in worrisome)

What I question:

In a VAR system, when all variables are endogenous, they all influence each-other.
Imagine you have a VAR system with 12 endogenous variables.

A one-unit shock in one variable will have an effect on each of these 12 variables.
Is this aggregated effect looked at when looking at an IRF between two variables?

So imagine I want to look at the shock of Var1 -> Var2.
Which would mean a one-unit shock in Var1, while keeping all  other variables constant.

However, a one-unit shock in Var1 - also has effects on the forecasted values of Var3 to Var12, and that change in forecasted values - have an effect on Var2.
So it would be a naive approach to look at the isolated effect of Var1 on Var2 while keeping all other variables constant, because that assumes that the change in Var1 does not cause a change in Var3 - Var12, which it does, and which as an impact on Var2.

So my question is, in IRF:

- Does it quantify isolated response of a one-unit shock of Var1 -> Var2 / while all other variables don't change
- Does it quantify the response of a one-unit shock in Var1, with all of its implications in all other variables - and look at the shock effect it has on Var2